# grant user execute access to a specific sql server agent job

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-agent

I would like to grant a SQL user account access to execute two specific SQL Agent jobs. I know I can grant the user SQLAgentOperatorRole, but this allows them to see and execute all SQL Agent jobs. I would prefer that they are only able to see and execute the jobs that I specify. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What if you right click the job and do properties and make them the owner?

Comment: If they are the owner won't it execute the T-SQL statements in the job under their account? I want the T-SQL to be executed by the sa account, because their account does not have the necessary access to the database to perform the steps in the job. I just want to give them the ability to execute the job.